# Invalid use of hook error fired when using hooks in custom hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need help with custom hooks. I created a custom hook to make api calls (useApiCall), I am calling it from my *authActions.js* file to send username and password to the server to signing up a new user. I am getting an error saying I am miss using hooks in the *useApiCall* functional component.

When I remove the logic for `useReducer` in the *useApiCall* functional component, it says I am misusing `useState` which comes after `useReducer`. It will not let me use hooks in the React functional component `useApiCall`.

I know I am breaking the rule of hooks, but what rule is that? I compared my code with other custom hooks and there is no difference.

In the `useApiCall` function I striped away all of my logic and used a single `useState` and got the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Hook called from (authActions): https://github.com/SMasood1/Chat-App/blob/main/client/src/context/authContext/authAction.js

Custom Hook (useApiCall): https://github.com/SMasood1/Chat-App/blob/main/client/src/context/a

```html
import { useState, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';

// Can make this more elegant and able to handle different types of methods and headers

const FETCH_INIT = 'FETCH_INIT';
const FETCH_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_SUCCESS';
const FETCH_FAILURE = 'FETCH_FAILURE';

const dataReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_INIT:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
        isError: false
      }
    case FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isError: false,
        data: action.payload
      }
    case FETCH_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isError: true,
        data: action.error
      }
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}
export const useApiCall = (initialUrl, initialMethod, initialData) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(dataReducer, {
    isLoading: false,
    isError: null,
    data: initialData ? initialData : ''
  })

  const [method, setMethod] = useState(initialMethod ? initialMethod : null);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl ? initialUrl : '');
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      await dispatch({ type: FETCH_INIT });
      let response;
      try {
        switch (method) {
          case 'GET':
            response = await fetch(url);
            break;
          case 'POST':
            response = await fetch(url, {
              method: method,
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
              },
              body: JSON.stringify(state.data)
            });
            break;
          default:
            console.log('Incorrect HTTP Request Method');
        }
        if (response.ok) {
          let resBody = await response.json();
          dispatch({ type: FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: resBody });
        } else {
          let resBody = await response.json();
          dispatch({ type: FETCH_FAILURE, error: resBody });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_FAILURE, error: 'Unable to send request!' });
      }
    }
    if (method && url) {
      fetchData();
    }
  }, [url, method, state.data]);
  return [state, setUrl, setMethod]
}
```

Error I received is below:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen
> for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: *Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component* -- This is the rule you are breaking. *in the React functional component useApiCall*  -- `useApiCall` is not a functional component and neither is your `authAction`. A React "component"  is a function or a class that can accept props and return a React element.

Comment: You received the error when using inside `OnSignin` or `OnSignup` or both?

Comment: @BrianThompson your explanation was really helpful. `OnSignup` is a functional component but I was treating it like a JS function by calling it as (OnSignup(...)) and that is my mistake. I have also realized hooks will not work for me here, I should be using vanilla JS to make api calls.